# Transform string with square brackets into list in where square bracket content is combined

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, grep

I want to transform the following string:

```
[test1 test2] test3 [test4 test5] test6 test7 [test8]
```

into the following array:

```
test1 test2, test3, test4 test5, test6, test7, test8
```

I have tried allot of things allready from $.grep to regEx. But it's just not cutting it. The closest I have come is the following:

```
var block_parts = text.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
var rest = text.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/g, '').split(" ");
var complete = $.merge(rest, block_parts);
```

But then it's not in the same order. (it will attach block_parts after rest)

Does anybody have an idea how I can do this?

Comment: Why there is a comma after `test6` ?

Comment: because I want to divide every single string but combine strings nested together with square blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double replace function.`\] +| +\[` would match all the `]` plus the following one or more space and also the closing `[` along with the preceding spaces. Just replace those matched characters with `,<space>` and again replace `[`, `]` with an empty string.

```
> var s = "[test1 test2] test3 [test4 test5] test6 test7 [test8]"
undefined
> var m = s.replace(/\] +| +\[/g, ", ").replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
undefined
> console.log(m)
test1 test2, test3, test4 test5, test6 test7, test8
```

**Update:**

```
> var m = s.replace(/\] +| +\[|\s+(?!\w+\])/g, ", ").replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
undefined
> console.log(m)
test1 test2, test3, test4 test5, test6, test7, test8
```

Comment: It's close but the thing that did not work is the test6 and test7 aren't devided

Comment: why it need to be divided?

Comment: because only the loose strings between the brackets should be a single entry in the array. Loose strings in the text without brackets should be divided into their own entry. soo: text1 text2 text3 should become text1, text2, text3

Comment: I have deleted the madam. It was more the ninja avatar :) Sorry my connecting genders to Indian(?) name skill is not that good.